# Google Cloud IAM roles on specific Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have a project that with a number of Cloud Functions deployed and I want to allow users to only administer certain functions, ensuring that they are not able to overwrite certain existing functions. Is it possible to set permissions on a per function basis like this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Roles can be granted to users on an entire project or on individual functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles), for project wide roles/permissions go to the Main Menu > IAM; and add them there.

**Edit**
To add IAM roles to specific functions only, go to Main Menu > Cloud Functions > click the checkbox at the left of the desired function > click "show info panel" (near the right) > permissions tab > add member

You can also use the [gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/add-iam-policy-binding) command

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at the permissions tab but it seems you can't actually add users there, just view who has what permissions

Comment: You are right, I have edited my answer with the correct way of adding permissions to individual functions